# For loop not working in creating Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a column that has individuals' names. 
I am trying to create a few dummy variables based on whether each of those names contains certain strings. I have a list of these strings, and I have extracted the names column as a pandas series. I am trying the following code, but cannot get the for loop to work. Would someone please be kind enough to point me toward the mistake I am making?

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.read_csv('address to .csv')
names = ds['name']
list = ['n1', 'n2', ...]
for l in list:
    l = names.str.contains(l, regex=False)
```

UPDATE: After Alexander's comment, I tried the following loop, but it still is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.read_csv('address to .csv')
names = ds['name']
list = ['n1', 'n2', ...]
for i, l in enumerate(list):
    v_i = names.str.contains(l, regex=False)
```

Comment: You are reassigning your loop variable (`l`), btw you should not use that letter as a variable because it is difficult to distinguish from one (`1`) and capital i (`I`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited the post with a new for loop that also is not working.

Comment: what's not working with the updated loop? if it's the series not being created, you want `df[l] = names.str.contains(l, regex=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to define and use the new variables, the logic would go like this :

```
list = ['n1', 'n2', ...]
var_dict = dict()
for l in list:
    var_dict[l] = names.str.contains(l, regex=False)
```